# How to process XML response. Failed to get Element Data

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following XML response code:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><CalculatePremiumResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><XmlResult><ResponseData>&#xD;
  <ErrorDetails>&#xD;
    <ErrorCode>1a</ErrorCode>&#xD;
    <ErrorDesc>Mandatory fields missing</ErrorDesc>&#xD;
    <Remarks>PIAM Code, Body Type</Remarks>&#xD;
    <WarningInd>N</WarningInd>&#xD;
  </ErrorDetails>&#xD;
</ResponseData></XmlResult></CalculatePremiumResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I want to get the `ErrorCode` element.

I am using this code which I presume should work but it doesn't:

```
rt.find("./s:Body/r:CalculatePremiumResponse/r:XmlResult/r:ResponseData/r:ErrorDetails/r:ErrorCode",ns)
```

Based on my understanding this should work. It works up to `ErrorDetails` but when I try to get the `ErrorCode` element then it returns empty.

Comment: Try the xpath expression like this and see if it works: `//s:Envelope/s:Body/CalculatePremiumResponse/XmlResult/ResponseData/ErrorDetails/ErrorCode`.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Your code isn't runnable, and to make it so will take us too much time.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the namespace by using `local-name()`:

```
//*[local-name()='CalculatePremiumResponse']/*[local-name()='XmlResult']/*[local-name()='ResponseData']/*[local-name()='ErrorDetails']/*[local-name()='ErrorCode']
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are a necessary evil but their evilness can make us nuts.

Nokogiri lets us cast them out if we are absolutely sure they have no use to us. From your XML sample it looks like this might be one of those times. Consider this code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <CalculatePremiumResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <XmlResult>
        <ResponseData>
          <ErrorDetails>
            <ErrorCode>1a</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDesc>Mandatory fields missing</ErrorDesc>
            <Remarks>PIAM Code, Body Type</Remarks>
            <WarningInd>N</WarningInd>
          </ErrorDetails>
        </ResponseData>
      </XmlResult>
    </CalculatePremiumResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
EOT
```

At this point we have an XML document that looks reasonable:

```
xml.to_xml
# => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
#    "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
#    "  <s:Body>\n" +
#    "    <CalculatePremiumResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n" +
#    "      <XmlResult>\n" +
#    "        <ResponseData>\n" +
#    "          <ErrorDetails>\n" +
#    "            <ErrorCode>1a</ErrorCode>\n" +
#    "            <ErrorDesc>Mandatory fields missing</ErrorDesc>\n" +
#    "            <Remarks>PIAM Code, Body Type</Remarks>\n" +
#    "            <WarningInd>N</WarningInd>\n" +
#    "          </ErrorDetails>\n" +
#    "        </ResponseData>\n" +
#    "      </XmlResult>\n" +
#    "    </CalculatePremiumResponse>\n" +
#    "  </s:Body>\n" +
#    "</s:Envelope>\n"
```

Running `remove_namespaces!` clears them out:

```
xml.remove_namespaces!
xml.to_xml
# => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
#    "<Envelope>\n" +
#    "  <Body>\n" +
#    "    <CalculatePremiumResponse>\n" +
#    "      <XmlResult>\n" +
#    "        <ResponseData>\n" +
#    "          <ErrorDetails>\n" +
#    "            <ErrorCode>1a</ErrorCode>\n" +
#    "            <ErrorDesc>Mandatory fields missing</ErrorDesc>\n" +
#    "            <Remarks>PIAM Code, Body Type</Remarks>\n" +
#    "            <WarningInd>N</WarningInd>\n" +
#    "          </ErrorDetails>\n" +
#    "        </ResponseData>\n" +
#    "      </XmlResult>\n" +
#    "    </CalculatePremiumResponse>\n" +
#    "  </Body>\n" +
#    "</Envelope>\n"
```

Allowing us to access nodes without worrying about them:

```
xml.at('ErrorCode').text # => "1a"
```

See [`remove_namespaces!`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Document#remove_namespaces%21-instance_method) for more information. I don't like, or advocate, removing them but sometimes it's the easier path.

NOTE: It's rarely a good idea to declare the complete path to a node. Browsers like to be "helpful" by allowing us to see what that path is in their debugging tools, but if a node's name changes or it moves in that path then your code will break. Instead find landmarks to navigate through it and locate your target node. That will reduce the fragility of dealing with XML/HTML documents.

If you absolutely *must* use namespaces, I'd recommend taking your question to the [Nokogiri mail-list](http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk) as that's where the really smart people hang out.